# iOS Swift - Dynamic Storyboard

Tags: dynamic, storyboard, swift2, segue

I am currently developing a new iOS app which is basically a decision tree app. All the data comes from an XML file (list of questions and logic path depending on answers). The XML reading is not a problem.

I know I could develop this by hardcoding everything in the storyboard, but I don't find this efficient. Design-wise, I don't know where to start to sort of build the storyboard dynamically. What stops me is that, based on what the user answers, some paths have different number of levels (or questions); so different storyboard screens.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: let me see if I understood your problem correctly, you have a bunch of possible view controllers that based on the XML reading you will be able to decide how to open them? is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build your views "manually" from code.